# Require module in LUA

Tags: module, lua

So I have a main LUA folder (extracted folder from zip) on C drive in C:\Lua\ folder. How can I require my own module that is located in: 
 `D:\Users\Admin\Desktop\LuaMod\Modules\myModule.lua`

to a file that is located in: `D:\Users\Admin\Desktop\LuaMod\main.lua` ?

I've search everything but nothing worked.

Comment: have you tried adding it to [package.path](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PackagePath)? though accessing files in an admin folder may still have hurdles related to account security. `package.path  = package.path .. "D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?.lua"`

Comment: Oh it actually worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Or you can invoke `dofile` instead of `require`: `local m = package.loaded.myModule or dofile([[D:\Users\Admin\Desktop\LuaMod\Modules\myModule.lua]]); package.loaded.myModule = m`

Answer (score 2):

You can add the path to `package.path`, this is a list of places lua will look for a file when you call `require`.

Simple solution:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?.lua"
```

This cause to require to look for the give `.lua` file in `D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/` but it will not look for the file in nested folders(ie `..\main\main.lua`)  and it wont find any `.dll` files.

To do that you can add more locations:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?.lua;D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?/?.lua;D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?/init.lua"
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?.dll;D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?/?.dll;D:/Users/Admin/Desktop/LuaMod/?/core.dll"
```

Resources:

[Lua User's Wiki: Package Path](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PackagePath)

[Lua Reference Manual: 5.3 Modules](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.3)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
require("Modules/myModule")
```

since one's in a sub-folder of the other and therefore can be indexed by slashes?